# How to dynamically render array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to dynamically render an array whose values will keep on changing.

I have a parent component

```
const Parent = () => {
    const arr = [];
    <Button onClick={()=>{
        arr.push("some value")        
       }}
    <Child data={arr}/>
}
```

```
export class Child extends React.Component {
    return(
            <h1>
                {this.props.data}
            </h1>
        )
}
```

So, initially the page will load blank with only a button. I want that when button is clicked then arr values should also be displayed. However, I see that even after adding values to array no values are displayed.

Comment: This is what state is for.

Comment: @GuyIncognito Can you please elaborate

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: Did you do any search before asking here? This is the basic of the basics.
You have to hold arr as a state, which you will update on each button press. React only rerenders when the state or props of a component updates.

Comment: Doing arr.push("some value") won't tell React that the value has changed. So your component won't rerender.  What you are currently doing is called mutating:
https://blog.logrocket.com/immutability-in-react-ebe55253a1cc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

arr.push is not a React way to go. There is something called state and everytime the state changed the component will re-render. Also if you want to show a list of elements you have to map over its values.

For more info [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#basic-list-component)

Try something like that(React hooks) :

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    
    return (
        <Button onClick={()=> setData([...data, "new value"])}
        <Child data={data}/>
    )
} 

const Child = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Data</h1>
            <div>
                {props.data.map(item => <span>{item}</span>)}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
const Parent = () => {  
const [arr, setarr] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        onClick={() => {
          setarr((oldArray) => [...oldArray, "some value"]);
        }}
      >
        Button
      </Button>
      <Child data={arr} />
    </div>
```

);

Child Component

```
export class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>{this.props.data}</h1>;
  }
}
```